# Angular controller $scope not being destroyed after jquery remove()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, destroy

In my application I have a directive that dynamically loads templates into a wrapper. The reason for how I implemented it this way is to have nice transitions.
It seems to work fine until I realized that when I load the same view a second time it seems like the controller in that view is duplicated.

There is a `$interval` running in one of the controllers that only applies changes if the view is correct, but when entering the view again it triggers twice (actually one for each time the view is loaded).

I have tried `$scope.$on('$destroy')` but that never fires for the controllers since I remove the element with jQuery. How can I unload the controller in current view completely when triggering `current.remove()`?

This is a snippet from the directive that replaces the views:

```
function setView(view) {
    var target = $('<div id="' + view + '" class="view ' + dir + '"></div>');
    var templateName = "'views/" + view + ".tpl.html'";
    var template = angular.element('<div ng-include="' + templateName + '"></div>');
    var current = el.find('#' + currentViewId);

    if (current.length === 0) {
        current = el.find('.view.current');
    }

    el.append(target);
    target.html(template);
    $compile(template)(scope);

    currentViewId = view;

    setTimeout(function () {
        current.removeClass('current').addClass((dir == 'next' ? 'prev' : 'next'));
        target.addClass('current').removeClass(dir);

        setTimeout(function () {
            current.remove();
        }, 500);
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but removing an Angular scope with jQuery doesn't sound like a good idea... Angular guys must have thought about that, and there must be a proper way of doing it. jQuery acting on Angular is just clumsy tinkering to me. Why don't you try templates, multiple controllers, ng-hide?...

Comment: Well, yes I guess this not, but since it is possible t add an element to the dom and using $complile there should be a proper way to remove it later.

Comment: I added current.children().scope().$destroy() just before current.remove() which seems to work.


I know this might not be the best solution to mix jquery with angular, but in some cases its way more efficient

Comment: In some cases, yes, let's say :)